# 2 Identical Like Buttons -- 1 Counter Increments, 2nd Counter Does Not

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I ran http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug on the 2 URL's below. Both debug test results returned identical results.

When you click the `Share This Story` button on the 1st link below, it increments and sticks fine.

When you click the `Share This Video` button on the 2nd link below, it increments but does not stick.

Code behind on both pages are identical.

Does anyone know why the 2nd like button will not retain its increment counter?

```
http://www.robertlanza.com/does-death-exist-new-theory-says-no-2/  (Like incrementing works)

http://www.robertlanzabiocentrism.com/video/wormhole/  (Like incrementing doesn't work)
```

Comment: FYI...I just added my fb_appId to the 2nd link iframe src -- whereas it is not present on the 1st link iframe src. Trying everything I can think of...

Comment: looking for smart facebook api experts

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to contact someone at Facebook to report a broken API for their like button?

Comment: Looking for Facebook Share button API gurus out there. Thanks.

Comment: Issue solved. No clue how or why, but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the links creation from `video/wormhole/` to `video-wormhole/`. I bet there is a path resolution issue with facebook looking for `video/` on the server when there isn't one. I noticed all your other links don't follow this `/` convention so for the sake of consistency I would change the path to `-`.

Comment: I really can't imagine that only web pages with a single-level directory structure are able to "Like" articles @corn3lius.

Comment: @frank13 that's not what Im saying. your Joomla (i think its Joomla) backend create a page that looks like it is in a subdirectory /video when in fact it isn't it is located on the main directory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean on this @corn3lius. The URL is simply a permalink. WordPress is the CMS. I can't change the URL as my client has already published the web address.

Comment: Plus I got the iframe code straight from Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: @frank13 your CMS is hiding the fact that the path doesn't exist and just because you got the plugin maker to get you a like link doesn't make the site real you can try it with `http://www.not_a_real_website.com` . guess what it gives you the code although the adresss doesn't exist. I am 95% sure your problem is the `/` but if you can't do anything about it, fine. dont say it isn't the issue if you haven't even tried this solution.

Comment: Sorry @corn3lius. I truly did not mean to make you angry. I did try your suggestion and it does not work (`http://bit.ly/LxHASC`). It just does not to make sense to me why other sites out there with lengthy URL's and multi-level directory structures can get their Like Buttons to work. And why, on certain permalink pages on my site, will they work and on this one it will not work.

Comment: @frank13 the like link did not change it still points to the other site `videos%2Fwormhole%2F` change your like link also.

Comment: Right, sorry. I changed it and still no luck.

Comment: Hey, good morning @corn3lius. So far you have been the only one willing to assist me on the perplexing issue. I greatly appreciate it. Might you have another suggestion for me to try? I need to get this issue fixed for my client and I simply have no clue on how or where to turn. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you changed the internal links to the new page with `-` see here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3423624/still_using_b_slash.PNG

Comment: Well, this is truly the most bizarre behavior I have ever experienced @corn3lius...I just checked my live page at `http://bit.ly/Mjs5vG` and it is working. I didn't do anything to it. Maybe there is propagation or latency on behalf of Facebook apps somewhere/somehow. Who knows. Just glad to be done with this one. Wow! Thanks for collaborating on it...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "does not work"?  Both seemed to function properly when I tested them.

Comment: What I mean by not working @GaelenN is this: I click the like button. I get the message that I (ie, my name appears) likes the page. Then I close the browser and re-open the browser again and the like button is not incremented. It does increment on the first link reference in my original question above.

Comment: Good morning @GaelenN. Curious if you have any other suggestions on what the issue with the FB Share button might be. Thanks!

Comment: @frank13: What did you do to fix it, or did it just resolve itself? I have this problem every now and then (for most of my websites it works fine, but some display the problem you described and it is unclear why).